Elliptic regularity theory and radial functions as test functions
Let $B$ the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^N$ and $E = \overline{C^\infty_{0,r}(B)}^{H^1_0(\Omega)}$ the space of radial functions in $H^1_0(B)$, where $C^\infty_{0,r}(B) = \{ u \in C^\infty_0(B) : u \text{ is radial} \}$. Define the functional $J : E \to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$
J(u) = \int_{B} |\nabla u(x)|^2 dx - \int_B |x|^\ell |u(x)|^p dx,
$$
with $2 < p < 2^\ast + 2\ell/(N-2)$ and $\ell > 0$. In this paper is proved there exists $u \in E$ critical point of $J$, that is, $J'(u) \varphi = 0$ for all $\varphi \in E$. The author also says; in the proof of Theorem 6 on p. 806, that by elliptic regularity theory one has $u \in C^2$(without more comments) and therefore it is a classical solution of
$$
(1) \quad -\Delta u = |x|^\ell |u|^{p-2}u\quad  B, \quad u = 0 \quad \partial B.
$$
How to justify this step? The most elliptic regularity theorems I have seem have as hypothesis that $u$ must be a weak solution of $(1)$, that is, $J'(u) \varphi = 0$ for all $\varphi \in H^1_0(B)$. Is it really enough to have $J'(u) \varphi = 0$ for all $\varphi \in C^\infty_{0,r}(B)$? Is there any elliptic regularity theorem involving radial function as test functions ?
Edit: The functional $J$ is not defined on $H^1_0(B)$, so it is not in $C^1(H^1_0(B), \mathbb{R})$ and (maybe) the usual Principle of Criticality Symmetric does not apply. Is there another version of this result which fits in this case?
Edit: $$
J(u) = \frac{1}{2}\int_{B} |\nabla u(x)|^2 dx - \frac{1}{p} \int_B |x|^\ell |u(x)|^p dx.
$$

The idea is to write $J(u)$ in radial coordinates, and view it as a minimisation problem in one dimension.
For this write $u(x) = \psi(|x|)$, and letting $\omega_{n} = |\partial B_1(0)|$ be the area of the unit $(n-1)$-sphere we have
\begin{equation}
J(u) = \omega_n \int_0^1 \frac12|\psi'(r)|^2 r^{n-1} - F(\psi) r^{\ell+n-1} \,\mathrm{d} r. \end{equation}
(Here I believe your $J(u)$ should take the form $|x|^{\ell}F(|u|)$ where $F$ satisfies $F(0) = 0$ and $F'(u) = |u|^p$, as is done in Theorem 6 of said paper. A factor $\frac12$ is also missing in the gradient part.)
Then if $u$ is a critical point, using outer variations (in $E$) one can derive an ODE the corresponding $\psi$ satisfies
\begin{equation}
  \psi'' + \frac{n-1}r \psi' + r^{\ell} |\psi|^{p} = 0,
\end{equation}
but then one sees that this is equivalent to the problem
\begin{equation}
  \Delta u + r^{\ell} |u|^p = 0
\end{equation}
since $u(x) = \psi(|x|)$. Thus $u$ (weakly) solves the elliptic problem, and one can then apply elliptic regularity* theory to infer that $u$ is a positive $C^2$ solution.
The above was a formal calculation, but I leave you to fill in the necessary details to make this precise in $E$.
*I assume the $C^2$ regularity is a standard result for semilinear problems of this type, but I do not know a precise reference nor proof. However showing said solution is positive follows from the strong maximum principle, noting that $\Delta u \leq 0$ weakly in $B$ and that $u$ vanishes on $\partial B$. A variant that applies in this weak setting can be found in Theorem 8.19 of Gilbarg & Trudinger's book.
Edited to add: To derive the ODE, consider variations of the type $u_t(x) = \psi(|x|) + t \varphi(|x|)$ with $\varphi(|\cdot|)$ a radial test function. Then we have
\begin{align*}
\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\right|_{t=0} J(u_t) 
&= \omega_n \int_0^1 \psi'(r)\varphi'(r) r^{n-1} - |u|^p \varphi r^{\ell+n-1} \mathrm{d}r\\
&= \omega_n \int_0^1 -\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}r}\left(\psi'(r) r^{n-1}\right)\varphi(r) - |u|^p \varphi r^{\ell+n-1} \mathrm{d}r\\
&= -\omega_n \int_0^1 \left(\psi''(r) + \frac{n-1}r \psi'(r) + |u|^p r^{\ell}\right)\varphi(r) r^{n-1}\mathrm{d}r,
\end{align*}
where we integrated by parts in the second line; note that $\varphi(1) = 0$ and the $r^{n-1}$ term vanishes at zero (if $u \in H^1_{0,\mathrm{rad}}$, use the "radial lemma" in the paper to argue that $|x|^{n-1} u(x)$ vanishes at the origin), you have no boundary terms.
Since $\varphi$ was arbitrary, we deduce that
\begin{equation}
  \psi''(r) + \frac{n-1}r \psi'(r) + |u|^p r^{\ell} = 0
\end{equation}
as claimed.

Thank you for your answer. What does it mean "using outer variations (in E
) " ?

Sorry, I didn't get how $\psi$ satisfies that ODE.  Could you please help me?

@LucasLinhares I added details for this - there was a mistake when I wrote $J(u)$ in radial coordinates, but this is now fixed (the $r^{n+1}$ should have been $r^{n-1}$).

I don't know if I miss something, but I think in the first an second line should be $|u|^p \varphi r^{\ell+n - 1}$.

Another question that happens to me. How to make sure there exists the derivatives $\psi''$? I know $\psi \in H^1(-1,1)$ because $u \in H^1(B)$. Also, by Sobolev embedding theorem in dimension one, I know $\psi \in C^{0,\gamma}([-1,1])$ for some $\gamma \in (0,1)$.

@LucasLinhares That was a typo, which I corrected. My derivation for the ODE in $\psi$ is purely formal; I don't assert $\psi''$ exists. In practice you only have the equation is satisfied in a weak sense (however ODE regularity should imply that $\psi$ is $C^2$ in $(0,1)$).
